# When does Neo4j release memory?

Tags: memory-management, neo4j

I have a bit of confusion regarding memory management.

I am using neo4j in an embedded mode within a java application. Version - 1.8.1. JVM version - 1.6

I have a single threaded loader with a for loop that contains a nested for loop. Inside the external for loop, I do `graphDb.beginTx();`, get an id of a test object from mysql and create a Node for that. In the inner for loop, I am querying mysql to get a bunch of related objects. I create nodes for them and the corresponding relationship with the node that I created in the external loop.

At the end of the external for loop, I do `tx.success()` and `tx.finish()`.

```
for (int x = 0; x < 10000000; x++) {
    Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
    Node n = graphDb.createNode();
    Long id = n.getId();
    System.out.println("ID: " + id);
    n.setProperty("TestId", x); 
    * * * get the mysql ids * * * *
    for (int y = 0; y < mysqlidlist; y++) {
        Node n1 = graphDb.createNode();
        Long id2 = n1.getId();
        n1.setProperty("InnerTestId", y);
        Relationship rel = n.createRelationshipTo(n1, NodeRelation.ATTRIBUTE);
        rel.setProperty("Weight", 0.3);
    }
    tx.success();
    tx.finish();
    tx = null;
}
```

Based on my readings, I thought that Neo4j would then release the memory that the transaction had grabbed. However, I see the memory usage always increasing and after some time it hits the Xmx setting. I will profile it to make sure there are no other leaks. I am setting all the other variables to null at the end and that should help GC reap it in a better way.

Am I wrong in my understanding? If so, what is the recommended best practice on memory management?

Next step - the Single Threaded loader will be extended to be a multi-threaded one and as such, want to make sure that the memory management and transaction management is robust.

Thanks so much!

Regards,

Sachin

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: yep.... the code...   for(int x =0; x<10000000;x++)
  {
   Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();

   Node n = graphDb.createNode();
   Long id = n.getId();
   System.out.println("ID: " + id);
   n.setProperty("TestId", x);

   *** get the mysql ids ****

   for(int y =0; y<mysqlidlist; y++)
   {
   
    Node n1 = graphDb.createNode();
    Long id2 = n1.getId();
    n1.setProperty("InnerTestId", y);
 
    Relationship rel = n.createRelationshipTo(n1, NodeRelation.ATTRIBUTE);
    rel.setProperty("Weight", 0.3);
   
   }
   
   tx.success();
   tx.finish();
   tx=null;
  }

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. What is the issue with reaching the heap limit? After all the GC will clean it up.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of massive insertion if you don't need transactions I suggest to use Batch Insertion.

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/batchinsert.html

---

Or, not recommended: If you want to use your snippet of code add something like: *if(y%1000==0) { tx.success();tx.finish()}* inside the for loop to commit and release the memory used every *n* inserts, but it will be slower

Comment: I do agree that batch would have been good; but I read that it is not recommended to be used in a multi-threaded manner. And we will be building our infrastructure to be more multithreaded. And yes, I was trying to do the success at certain intervals and it does help, but I think neo4j still caches a lot and does not release it. I was trying what Wes recommended to turn off the cache and that definitely helps in not reaching the Xmx limit. And my next question was going to be if that can be turned off and on dynamically? Currently, I do it at the start.

Answer (score 0):

You could try turning off caching (use cache_type=none). docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/configuration-caches.html

Comment: Wes - I turned off the cache and that definitely helps in not reaching the Xmx limit. And my next question was going to be if that can be turned off and on dynamically? Currently, I do it at the start. Thanks much!

Comment: You might have to reinitialize the GraphDatabase to change it--not sure. Maybe one of the Neo guys can comment.